# print out rows from database in a table

Tags: php, html, mysql, while-loop

Why do I need to use echo to print MYSQL data to my table?

Take a look at my code sample.

**what I am trying to do**

Select and show all data in the query in a table.

**Problem 1**

This works: `<td><?php echo "<br>". $row["testName"].  "<br>";?></td>`

This does not: `<td><?php  $row["testName"] ?></td>`

I feel the second option should work but does not.

*(not such a big deal just feels wrong)*

**Problem 2**

I would also like all data to be in one table not for the loop to create a new table every time.

```
    $sql = "SELECT testName, userID FROM  `results` WHERE  `userID` = '$something' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>

        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>some text Score</th>
                <th>Date Taken</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td><?php  $row["testName"] ?></td>
                <td><?php  $row["userID"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "<br>". $row["testName"].  "<br>";?></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
<?php
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: `<?php  $row["testName"] ?>` does *nothing*. You're not actually `echo`ing it. If sort-tags are on, or in PHP higher than 5.4.0, you can do `<?= $row["testName"] ?>`, which echos it.

Comment: 1. You forgot to `echo` the variable. 2. Move the first part and the last part of the table out of the `while` loop (to before and after it).

Comment: Change your second option to `<td><?=  $row["testName"] ?></td>`

Comment: Thanks guys, ill do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display value from database then you must need to use echo. because **$row["testName"]** contains some value but which value it is, that you can see after echoing it.

To display data in single table try **below code**:

```
    <?php 
$sql = "SELECT testName, userID FROM  `results` WHERE  `userID` = '$something' ";
      $result = $conn->query($sql); ?>
      <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>some text Score</th>
                <th>Date Taken</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    <?php

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td><?php echo $row["testName"] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["userID"] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "<br>". $row["testName"].  "<br>";?></td>
        </tr>

    <?php } ?> 
 </table>
   <?php }else 
       {
         echo "0 results";
        }
```

Comment: Plus 1 and check, nice quick fix

Comment: Thanks Keep helping :)

Answer (score 1):

**Description**

```
void echo ( string $arg1 [, string $... ] )
```

`Outputs all parameters`. No additional newline is appended.

> echo is not actually a function (it is a language construct), so you
>   are not required to use parentheses with it. echo (unlike some other
>   language constructs) does not behave like a function, so it cannot
>   always be used in the context of a function. Additionally, if you want
>   to pass more than one parameter to echo, the parameters must not be
>   enclosed within parentheses.
>
> echo also has a shortcut syntax, where you can immediately follow the
>   opening tag with an equals sign. Prior to PHP 5.4.0, this short syntax
>   only works with the short_open_tag configuration setting enabled.

Ref : http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Answer (score 1):

Run while like this

```
  <?php
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
  <tr>
         <th scope="row">1</th>
         <td><?php  echo $row["testName"] ?></td>
         <td><?php  echo $row["userID"] ?></td>
         <td><?php echo "<br>". $row["testName"].  "<br>";?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
```